# Convert single model, in a model that contains a grouping with a key that will be used as the header

Tags: c#, list, xamarin.forms, model

I a have a single model example

```
public class Phone
{
    public string BrandName {get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set; }
    public decimal Price {get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to convert this model as example below?:

```
 public class PhoneGroup : List<Phone>
{
    public string BrandName { get; private set; }

    public PhoneGroup(string brandName)
        : base()
    {
        BrandName = brandName;
    }

    public PhoneGroup(string brandName, IEnumerable<Phone> source)
        : base(source)
    {
        BrandName = brandName;
    }
}
```

Grouping using the brandName property

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Grouped ListView.

Model:

```
public class Answer
{
    public string Ds_DescricaoPergunta { get; set; }
}
public class AnswerList : List<Answer>
{
    public string Questions { get; set; }
    public List<Answer> Answers => this;
}
```

Xaml:

```
<ListView IsGroupingEnabled="true" ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfAnswers}">
    <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Label Text="{Binding Questions}" BackgroundColor="Purple"/>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Label Text="{Binding Ds_DescricaoPergunta}"/>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
private List<AnswerList> _listOfAnswers;
public List<AnswerList> ListOfAnswers { get { return _listOfAnswers; } set { _listOfAnswers = value; base.OnPropertyChanged(); } }

public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var Q1List = new AnswerList()
    {
        new Answer(){ Ds_DescricaoPergunta="Q1_Answer1"},
        new Answer(){ Ds_DescricaoPergunta="Q1_Answer2"},
        new Answer(){ Ds_DescricaoPergunta="Q1_Answer3"},
    };
    Q1List.Questions = "Q1";

    var Q2List = new AnswerList()
    {
        new Answer(){ Ds_DescricaoPergunta="Q2_Answer1"},
        new Answer(){ Ds_DescricaoPergunta="Q2_Answer2"},
        new Answer(){ Ds_DescricaoPergunta="Q2_Answer3"},
    };
    Q2List.Questions = "Q2";

    var Q3List = new AnswerList()
    {
        new Answer(){ Ds_DescricaoPergunta="Q3_Answer1"},
        new Answer(){ Ds_DescricaoPergunta="Q3_Answer2"},

    };
    Q3List.Questions = "Q3";

    var Q4List = new AnswerList()
    {
        new Answer(){ Ds_DescricaoPergunta="Q4_Answer1"},
        new Answer(){ Ds_DescricaoPergunta="Q4_Answer2"},
        new Answer(){ Ds_DescricaoPergunta="Q4_Answer3"},
        new Answer(){ Ds_DescricaoPergunta="Q4_Answer4"},
    };
    Q1List.Questions = "Q4";

    var list = new List<AnswerList> { Q1List, Q2List, Q3List, Q4List };
    ListOfAnswers = list;

    this.BindingContext = this;
}
}
```

[image]